# WSO2 EI 6.2.0 CAR deployment broken - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: wso2, osgi, osgi-bundle, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

we have a project, where we have been using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator for a year or so. The implementation became relatively complex over time and it involves combination of proxies, APIs, templates, custom mediators and message broker. This gets deployed via a single CAR deployment artifact. The common code has been shared as WSO2>Extensions>JavaLibraryProject (WSO2 DevStudio). This library gets archived into CAR as:

```
<artifact name="M2E-Commons" version="1.0.1" type="lib/library/bundle" serverRole="ApplicationServer">
  <file>M2E-Commons-1.0.1.jar</file>
</artifact>
```

This had been working for us just fine for all of the past releases, but got broken with WSO2 EI 6.2.0

This is the beginning of the log while deploying on WSO2 EI 6.1.1:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-09 14:33:52,337]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Deploying Carbon Application : M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car... {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-09 14:33:52,350]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer} -  OSGi bundle in file:///opt/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1523284432337M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car/M2E-Commons_1.0.1/M2E-Commons-1.0.1.jar location is about to be installed to Carbon Server. {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-09 14:33:52,351]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer} -  OSGi bundle M2E-Commons installed to Carbon Server. {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-09 14:33:52,369]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer} -  OSGi bundle M2E-Commons successfully started on Carbon Server. {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-09 14:33:52,369]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer} -  Deploying Class mediators from file : /opt/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1523284432337M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car/M2E-Device_1.0.0/M2E-Device-1.0.0.jar {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-09 14:33:52,370]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer} -  Deploying Class mediators from file : /opt/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1523284432337M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car/M2E-Flic_1.0.0/M2E-Flic-1.0.0.jar {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer}
```

And this is the same CAR deployed on WSO2 EI 6.2.0:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 22:29:46,703]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Deploying Carbon Application : M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car... {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 22:29:46,810]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer} -  Deploying Class mediators from file : /opt/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1523053786703M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car/M2E-Device_1.0.0/M2E-Device-1.0.0.jar {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 22:29:46,810]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer} -  Deploying Class mediators from file : /opt/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1523053786703M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car/M2E-Flic_1.0.0/M2E-Flic-1.0.0.jar {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 22:29:46,810]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer} -  Deploying Class mediators from file : /opt/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1523053786703M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car/M2E-M2L_ISS_1.0.0/M2E-M2L_ISS-1.0.0.jar {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 22:29:46,810]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer} -  Deploying Class mediators from file : /opt/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1523053786703M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car/M2E-M2T_1.0.1/M2E-M2T-1.0.1.jar {org.apache.synapse.deployers.ClassMediatorDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 22:29:46,881] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} -  Deployment of the Synapse Artifact from file : /opt/wso2ei-6.2.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1523053786703M2E-CAP_1.0.16.car/M2E-ISS.LightOff_1.0.0/M2E-ISS.LightOff-1.0.0.xml : Failed! {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer}
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sk/m2ms/wso2/m2e/M2Mediator
```

Apparently the OSGi bundle M2E-Commons deployment was not prioritized properly to start before the rest of artifact deployments - resulting in NoClassDefFoundError.

Do you have any ideas?
Can this be solved via some OSGi compliant mechanism/concept?
Or this is a valid bug to be submitted against WSO2?

Thank you in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

An error like `NoClassDefFoundError` will never happen because of start ordering. It means that a bundle uses the package `sk.m2ms.wso2.m2e` but neither imports nor contains that package. That is an error in the construction of the bundle, so if this is not a bundle that you built yourself then I would suggest that this is indeed a bug that should be reported to the vendor.

Comment: Neil, thanks for your response! Yeah, your remark makes sense. I have opened a ticket against the vendor: https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2114